# Can't delete snake's tail according to his head's movement

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, position, coordinates

EDIT #1.
Now i see that my functions doesnt work with this game so please forget them.
Still haven't found a solution, saw some documentation about Queue's as fjf2002 mentioned but it's way too complex to me at this momment. Tried to make a snake[20] array to store coordinates by 2
    {1, 1, 1, 2} would be: Head (1,1) Tail (1,2) on the map. Still can't figure how to move it around the map and make the tail follow the head. My mind is blank after trying everything and getting frustrated by my lack of experience. Im not allowed to use anything beyond two-dimensional arrays. Meaning that no structs, no queues, no stacks... This is supposed to be done without using those and profesor says that is more easier than i think. (Dont post that i should ask him for the solution as he keeps saying the same without answering my questions). Any idea would help me greatly...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
im using VisualStudio 2013 and programming in C language.
Was looking for a solution in the past 2 days and found nothing over internet to help me. Saw dozens of different snake games in english and spanish but i can't understand them due to zero explaining of their programs or due to my lack of experience.

Tried everything of my knowledge without success and i can't really come up with a solution by my own.

**I have:**

-**Function** to generate the map.
-**Function** to move the snake:

```
COORD cxy;
#define posicion(x,y) {(cxy.X)= (x);(cxy.Y)= (y); SetConsoleCursorPosition((GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)), (cxy) );}

int tablero[20][20], posx = 0, posy = 0;

void movimientoSnake(){
    int m = 1, k = 0, tail = 3;
    char dir = 'd';

    do{

        if (kbhit()){
            dir = getch();

            if (dir == 'w'){
                m = 0;
                k = -1;
            }
            if(dir == 's'){
                m = 0;
                k = 1;
            }
            if (dir == 'a'){
                m = -1;
                k = 0;

            }
            if (dir == 'd'){
                m = 1;
                k = 0;
            }
        }
        else{

            Sleep(500);

            posicion(posx += m, posy += k);
            printf("%d", 1);
            posicion(posx - tail, posy);
            printf("%d", 0);

        }

    } while (2 > 1);
```

*The snake moves OK according to wasd keys, and it leaves a trail with 1's (map is full of 0's).
*It moves based on position: position(x,y) of the map (moves there) printf("%d", 1); (prints an 1). for example

The main problem is when i want to delete the trail when i move down, delete the last position while at the same time im printing the new one ahead.

If possible i would like a solution without too much complex (using too many libraries) as by now i only know:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

I tried to store coordinates on arrays as i saw in almost 90% of snake games out there but i dont understand the concept so i ended up with a bunch of tries without success.

**Any ideas?
Thank you very much in advance.**

Comment: @Weather_Vane its an infinite loop because i wanted it for testing.

Comment: For an infinite loop, it is common to write `while (1)`.

Comment: What is it you don't understand the concept of? Arrays in general, or using an array to hold the position of the snake?

Comment: I was thinking on leave a trail with numbers depending on direction so numbers move to left if fhey find a 1... rigth if 2...

Answer (score 1):

So let us summarize:

1. Knowing only the coordinates of the head of the snake, how to determine the coordinates of the tail?
2. Since the snake may have several turns, there is no straight forward way.

> I tried to store coordinates on arrays as i saw in almost 90% of snake games out there

Seems to be the only solution.

> but i dont understand the concept

- You should store the positions occupied by the snake in an array. You have to keep track which array elements are currently occupied, where the head and where the tail is stored.
- Or you use the above as an already implemented product: a data structure that allows easy access to first and last element. Read 
  about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO , http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/ .

Comment: Seems a good option. But we haven't saw queue's in class. Aren't there any other possibility?. Other snake codes have something like Snake[0].y which function/structure is that?. Thanks.

Comment: The "[]" braces indicate (most times) the use of an array. ".y" means: The array entries are of a class or struct type, which has a member called "y".

Comment: There will be no way around the fact that you need to store the all the coordinates occupied by the snake. Read about implementing a queue data structure by hand, using an array. If your snake does not grow, a circular buffer could be a bit simpler solution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer